Chf. of a sum of independent r.v. is the product of chfs. Is the converse true?
Let suppose that we have a random variables $X$ and $Y$ whose chfs. can be written as:
$$\forall u \in\mathbb{R},\quad\Phi_X(u) = f(u)\Phi_Y(u).$$
Does it mean that we can write $X=Z+Y$ where $Z$ is a random variable with chf. $f$ ?
Thank you very much!

Finding a $Z$ on the same probability space may not possible, but you can certainly say that $X$ has the same distribution as $Z+Y$ where $Z$ is independent of $Y$ with charactersitic function $f$.

If you assume that $Z$ and $Y$ are independent, yes.

It boils down to if $f$ is a valid characteristic function. If it is, I think the answer is confirmative. If $f(u)=1$, obviously no.

Thank you very much for these answers. @ZackFisher, if $f(u) =1$, its inverse Fourier transform is a Dirac in 0 and it is thus valid

Yeah. That's not a good example. But if we just take the ratio of two arbitrary chfs., the result won't necessarily be another chf. If $\phi_X(tu)=e^{-u^2/2}$ is standard normal chf. and $\phi_Y(u)=(1+u^2)^{-1}$ is standard Laplace chf. The inverse Fourier transform of their ratio is proportional to $(2-x^2)e^{-x^2/2}$, which could be negative.

Let $P(X=1)=1$ and $P(Y=0)=\frac{1}{2}=P(Y=1)$. Then $\Phi_X(u)=e^{iu}$ and $\Phi_Y(u)=\frac{1}{2}(1+e^{iu})$.
If $X=Y+Z$, then $P(Z=0)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $P(Z=1)=\frac{1}{2}$, thus $\Phi_Z=\Phi_Y$, but $\Phi_X\neq \Phi^2_Y$.

$\varphi_{X+Y}=\varphi_X\times \varphi_Y$ does not imply that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Example $X=Y$ with $X$ standard Cauchy, namely $\varphi_X(t)=e^{-|t|}.$
